# How to draw a rectangle in a browser page using java and jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, html

I'm pretty new to jsp-java in practice.
I'm trying to write a script that allows users to draw a rectangle by clicking and dragging with the mouse.
But, what i really don't understand is : is it possible to draw a rectangle without building a support like a window Jpanel or JFrame because i want a display on a webpage not a on new opened window.
How this rectangle will output on a browser's page ?
How to switch from a java desktop application window to a webpage window ?
I don't want the users have to open a new window application, it will be cool that the users can directly draw their rectangle using their mouse in a webpage.
Sorry for some repetitions, i was just trying to be as clear as possible as i just begin in all that stuff !
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A jsp is rendered server side. If you want users to draw, you'll need HTML5 or javascript on the client side.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a [`<fieldset>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) or a `<div style="border:1">`. User could *resize* the component using JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: why not use javascript? or html5 for that task?

Comment: It is possible to create image on the server side but i agree this is more fastidious!Just wanted to try to implement something different not on the client-side but on server-side, and as i have began learning java..

Comment: Here are some examples to draw rectangle using Html5. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mixing technologies. The answer to your question is "no". You can't do that with JSP.

But you could with others, like mentionned in comments, html5 using a canvas would let you draw following the mouse position.

If you are really looking to work with Java, you could use an Applet, which is embedded in a web page.

Comment: Don't think it is impossible, but fastidious and not practical. And i would certainly have to mix several langages as you said. Just wanted to test a different thing.